# BigQuery is not a constructor Error when connecting to Google BigQuery with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

According to all the tutorials I found (one example in the link below) the following snippet should allow me to connect and query Google BigQuery. But whatever combination of sending credential jsons, or not, always results in the same error "BigQuery is not a constructor" I am currently testing this through the google online cloud shell. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/BigQuery#createJob

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

const query = 'SELECT * FROM `random.table` LIMIT 100';

bigquery.createQueryJob(query).then(function(data) {
    var job = data[0];
    var apiResponse = data[1];
    console.log(job.getQueryResults())
    return job.getQueryResults();
  });
```

Error

```
/home/v/testServer.js:2
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
                 ^
TypeError: BigQuery is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user_name/testServer.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This issue seems to be generated as it is required to add the `{` `}` symbols to the [BigQuery import](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#using_the_client_library). I have just made a test by adding the following import line and it worked perfectly:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
```